# How to use jquery to post dropdown values to another php form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

Thank you for your time, I have spent a good part of my day googling every way I can think of and I cant find a clear simple answer. Ive tried everything I can think of and have found great answers here. I sure hope someone can help me. Ive done most of my research on jquery on there site and to no avail I'm still looking for answers. Ive found some help full articles here also, I just must not be fully understanding or am overlooking some simple facts. I'm definitely new to all of this so lets take it nice and easy ! To start I am taking user form data and validating with a php script that will hopefully be talking to a data base and storing form info.

So here are the forms guts:

```
    <form method="post" action="test.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
    <div class="grid_6" id="register">
    <center><h4>Required Information</h4></center>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="trew">Contact Phone:</label>
    <input name="txtAreaCode" id="txtAreaCode" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" value=""type="text">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 200, 46);">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
    <input name="txtPrefix" id="txtPrefix" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" value=""type="text">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 200, 46);">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
    <input name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" style="width: 45px;" maxlength="4" value=""type="text">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 200, 46);">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
    <input name="txtPhoneExt" id="txtPhoneExt" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="10" value=""type="text">
    ext.
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
      <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="school">Name of School:</label>
      <input name="school" id="school" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="title">Affiliation</label>
      <select name="title">
      <option selected="NULL">Please Select</option>
      <option value="student">Student</option>
      <option value="parent">Parent</option>
      <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
      <option value="booster">Booster</option>
      <option value="clubpres">Club President</option>
      <option value="principal">Principal</option>
      <option value="ptsa">PTSA</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6" id="contactinfo">
    <center><h4>Additional Information</h4></center>
    <p>
      <label for="color">School Colors:</label>
      <input name="color" id="color" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="mascot">Mascot:</label>
      <input name="mascot" id="mascot" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="tagline">Tagline/Motto:</label>
      <input name="tagline" id="tagline" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="sbsize">Approximate Student Body Size:</label>
      <input name="sbsize" id="sbsize" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="level">Interest Level:</label>
      <select name="level">
      <option value="1">Interested</option>
      <option value="2">Slightly Interested</option>
      <option value="3">Moderately Interested</option>
      <option value="4">Highly Interested</option>
      <option value="5">Extremely Interested</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="verify">1 + 3 =</label>
      <input name="verify" id="verify" class="small" type="text" />
    </p>
    <button class="fr" type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

I take this form and make it all pretty with jquery now this is where I am getting the most headache of my life, I spent an hr rewriting from scratch thinking I had syntax errors or something. Come to find out this little gem was the problem, its all good we all make mistakes. Here is the jquery form file, this isn't my project i not even sure if this is needed but here is the source of my problems, Ive figured them all out but 1 (hopefully !).

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="./img/form/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

    $.post(action, { 
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        txtAreaCode: $('#txtAreaCode').val(),
        txtPrefix: $('#txtPrefix').val(),
        txtPhone: $('#txtPhone').val(),
        txtPhoneExt: $('#txtPhoneExt').val(),
        zip: $('#zip').val(),
        school: $('#school').val(),
        title: singleValues = $("#title").val(),
        color: $('#color').val(),
        mascot: $('#mascot').val(),
        tagline: $('#tagline').val(),
        sbsize: $('#sbsize').val(),
        level: $('#level').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        }
    );

    });

    return false; 

});

    });
```

Alright now here is where I see the problem, im trying to get the values of the multiple choice to post to the last and final piece of code my php file that preforms the verification, Ive stripped down the fluff for debugging . But am sure that ive provided more than enough to fix. so here is the php...

```
  <?php
if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
}

if(trim($_POST['email']) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your email.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

if(trim($_POST['txtAreaCode']) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your txtAreaCode.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $txtAreaCode = trim($_POST['txtAreaCode']);
}

if(trim($_POST['txtPrefix']) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your txtPrefix.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $txtPrefix = trim($_POST['txtPrefix']);
}
    if(trim($_POST['txtPhone']) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your txtPhone.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $txtPhone = trim($_POST['txtPhone']);
}

if(trim($_POST['zip']) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your zip.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $zip = trim($_POST['zip']);
}

if(trim($_POST['school']) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your school.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $school = trim($_POST['school']);
}


if(trim($_POST['title']) != 'NULL') {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! You must enter your title.</div>';
    exit();
} else {
    $title = trim($_POST['title']);
}


if(trim($_POST['verify']) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($_POST['verify']) != '4') {
        echo '<div class="error-message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
        exit();
    }   
        echo 'working';     

?>
```

Now im sure there are many workarounds, I would like to know what I need to do to get this all working. I cant scrap jQuery as its a must for the project, Im sure it should be a simple fix. Fingers crossed as always forgive me for going overboard, i just feel I should let you guys see what my problem is. Ive noticed that if I dont use the 2nd piece of code at all it works wonders, but like i said I need to use it....

From what I gather im clearly doing something wrong in the .post action section as it isnt posting values of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird isn't it, that you've nicely set IDs for all the other items in your form except for your drop downs, where you've only set names.

Forms submit the values of the controls using name, but you're referencing the value in your jquery code using id ('#').

So just try changing your dropdown declarations to have ids... like this:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
    <div class="grid_6" id="register">
    <center><h4>Required Information</h4></center>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="trew">Contact Phone:</label>
    <input name="txtAreaCode" id="txtAreaCode" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" value=""type="text">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 200, 46);">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
    <input name="txtPrefix" id="txtPrefix" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" value=""type="text">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 200, 46);">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
    <input name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" style="width: 45px;" maxlength="4" value=""type="text">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 200, 46);">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
    <input name="txtPhoneExt" id="txtPhoneExt" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="10" value=""type="text">
    ext.
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
      <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="school">Name of School:</label>
      <input name="school" id="school" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="title">Affiliation</label>
      <select name="title" id="title">
      <option selected="NULL">Please Select</option>
      <option value="student">Student</option>
      <option value="parent">Parent</option>
      <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
      <option value="booster">Booster</option>
      <option value="clubpres">Club President</option>
      <option value="principal">Principal</option>
      <option value="ptsa">PTSA</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6" id="contactinfo">
    <center><h4>Additional Information</h4></center>
    <p>
      <label for="color">School Colors:</label>
      <input name="color" id="color" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="mascot">Mascot:</label>
      <input name="mascot" id="mascot" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="tagline">Tagline/Motto:</label>
      <input name="tagline" id="tagline" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="sbsize">Approximate Student Body Size:</label>
      <input name="sbsize" id="sbsize" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="level">Interest Level:</label>
      <select name="level" id="level">
      <option value="1">Interested</option>
      <option value="2">Slightly Interested</option>
      <option value="3">Moderately Interested</option>
      <option value="4">Highly Interested</option>
      <option value="5">Extremely Interested</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="verify">1 + 3 =</label>
      <input name="verify" id="verify" class="small" type="text" />
    </p>
    <button class="fr" type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome , makes total sense I shouldn't have overlooked this. Thank you so much I am very thankful you have helped me  . This is the fix .

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of these type forms for my company's application, and there's definitely some shortcuts you can take.

1. Serialize the data rather than using pure ID's.  That way, you don't have to reference EVERY id to submit a form.
2. Use a validation script on the front end, it'll cut down on the back-end validation you have to worry about reporting back on after the submit.  You can't get rid of back end validation, but using a front-end validation tool allows you to quickly and effectively warn the user of a potential problem without the "cost" of a submit.  I really like the [inline validator script](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).
3. If you post your data via an Ajax call rather than just a post, you can use the success callback to deal with issues like validation, success modal windows, etc.
4. When I do have to do a back-end validation alert, I ususally just make one common alert div at the top of the form and report back to that via the success element of the Ajax call (usually sending JSON)  Remember, success on Ajax means the transaction happened, you can still have errors report back through from PHP and have to deal with an error case.  By only doing one alert box, I save myself a ton of work and syntax, since most all errors get dealt with on the front end and the back-end is simply redundancy.

So, here's a sample of how I'd do a form on my site:

```
<div id="error" style="display:none"></div>  <!-- error div, hidden -->

<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="validator">  <!-- don't forget names! -->
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name2" class="validator">
  <button id="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#submit').click(function() {   // onclick of submit, submit form via ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: "url_to_submit_to.php",  //url to submit to
      timeout: 30000,
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#form).serialize(),  //gets form data, sends via post to processing page
      dataType: 'json',             //what to do with returned data, in this case, it's json
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
         alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
      },
      success: function(outstuff){
         if (outstuff.success == 1) {       //
             alert('success')
         } else {
             $('#error').html('there is an error, do something');
             //Do other stuff
         }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like a FANTASTIC idea I totally get how looking at it from a larger scale validation on the page is better, if I were not in such a time crunch Id start implementing immediately as this form will see allot of click thru's every day. I appreciate your suggestion and will start 'playing in the sandbox' so to speak and see if this is for me, my main worry is getting it to work with our previous designers code but I'm sure I can figure it out. Thank you for your time its people like you that make 'web' so much better with these types of ideas and practices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should add and id to the drop down menu, otherwise you can't call it as `$("#title")` in jquery

and in your jquery, it will try to submit when the page loads as you're calling it like

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

Try to change it to `$(function(){`

Hope it will work

Comment: Yep it was the id's, thank you for your assistance I went ahead and made your correction also.